# Outlook addin not working on Office 2013 or Office 2016

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've submitted my outlook add-in 6 times now and every time the certification failed for a different reason. The last rejection reason I got was that my add-in didn't work on Office 2013 and Office 2016 (which they also refer to as O365 Perpetual).

I develop on a Mac and I have no idea how to go about debugging why my add-in is not working on those older Offices. Can't I just drop support for older Office suites? How could I test these environments?

I'm pretty close to quitting and just not publishing my outlook addin. I have never experienced a worse app review process.

Comment: Clarify, this in an add-in in Access or an add-in in Outlook?

Comment: @June7 It's an Outlook Add-in

Comment: Still want to make sure I understand. I should open Access and with Add-in Manager add this Outlook Add-in? Where can I find the add-in?

Comment: You can install virtual machines with Office 2013 and 2016 where you can debug the add-in. Office add-ins are supported by Office applications starting from 2013.

Comment: Please be aware that the validation team will not be able to discuss individual submission results on Stack Overflow.
As per our documentation, we cannot and do not provide customer support for individual submissions on StackOverflow. You can raise a Customer Support ticket here: https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport  
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Comment: Here is a couple of links that may assist you, one will give you access to free Windows 10 virtual machines and the other, a free 30 day trial for an O365 tenant.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab

Comment: How can I install older versions of Office tho? Also is it mandatory to support it? None of our users use these versions.

Comment: If you want to be published on the Office Store, you need to support all the platforms for your minimum required API Set in your manifest. If you do not need Office 2013, and Office 2016, You can set your Minimium API Set, then setting this to 1.5 will drop support for those versions. (1.4 was the last version supported by these). When you submit, make a note that your minimum API set means that you will not run those Office clients.

Comment: As a side option though, if you do not want to support OWA/window clients at all (even the newer ones), then your add-in isn't allowed on the Office Store. You can however, manually sideload the add-in. (either at the admin level or individual user level)

Comment: Installing older versions of office: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be published on the Office Store, you need to support all the platforms for the minimum [Outlook API Requirement Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets) in your manifest.

If you do not need to support Outlook 2013 or Outlook 2016, you can set your minimum API requirement set to 1.5, which will drop support for those versions (1.4 was the last version supported by those versions of Outlook). When you submit to the Office Store, please make a note that your minimum API set means that the add-in will not run in those Office clients.